# boost::heap::arity, what is it?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std

I am cleaning a legacy code. Inside I have a priority queue from 1986 ^_^.
After interfacing it with a C++ interface more and less compliant with the std. I did some benchmark between all priority_queues on the "market" (std + boost).

Boost provides a priority_queue name `boost::d_ary::heap`. This queue necessitates a parameter named `boost::heap::arity<int>`, the documentation of Boost does not provide a clear explanation, just a link to the implementation of the heap.

Presently I put `boost::heap::arity<128>` I am really satisfied but I do not know what does it mean. One of you, have a bit of explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often priority queues are implemented as [heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). Heaps are full trees with a partial order of top. Such a full trees is generally stored in an array. The arity describes how many children each node of the tree has at most. For an arity of two the tree is a binary tree and so on. From an abstract standpoint the tree corresponding to a heap has a depth of roughly `log(n)/log(d)` (where `d` is the arity of the heap).

The performance of a heap does (theoretically) depend on the arity, in practice what matters most is cache efficiency. You should run some benchmarks to test the performance. I think that a value of 128 is rather high, I personally use the range from 2 to 16.

Comment: Great ! Maybe 128 children is a bit too much +1

Comment: "Trees are often stored embedded into arrays" - did you mean "Heaps"?

Comment: Well, I meant trees in the context oh heaps, fixing it now.